# How to output elementary streams with android media recorder?

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I want to output elementary video streams with media recorder in android for the purpose of streaming with live555. In essence, I want to get media recorder to output an `MPEG-4 Video Elementary Stream file` (an `.m4e` file) or an `H.264 Video Elementary Stream file` (an `.264` file). Is it possible to do that with media recorder on android? Or is there any other way to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, as I understand, that it is not easy to do that with `MediaRecorder` while recording. You may do that without much difficulty, using `ffmpeg` once the video is recorded. The reason is that, `MediaPlayer` cannot record as elementary streams. Even if we record video only, it will be put in a container format such as 3GPP or MP4. Now, for tools like `ffmpeg` to work on these files, they need the 3GPP or MP4 header information must be present on the recorded file. But, `MediaPlayer` will write those headers to the file only after it finished recording.

Answer (score 1):

From the MediaRecorder APIs I see that you have to call the setOutputFormat() before calling prepare(), this limits you to select one of the available options - 3GP/MP4. Hence you can use your own parser to operate on the dump from the mediarecorder, which can give you elementary streams.

Comment: Do you know about any library that will do that?

Comment: I can think of FFmpeg player which is an open source player and there is lots of info available online and stackoverflow to use it. You can have a look at the link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android

Comment: This link too might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899044/ffmpeg-extract-elementary-streams-from-mp4